# Angular standalone -ngrx effects dependency injection , how to configure it without any NullInjectorError: No provider for MatDialog

Tags: angular, frontend, ngrx, ngrx-effects, angular-standalone-components

Not sure it is an error or config issue..

I have ngrx effect which has a dependency to MatDialog (whenever a success action happens in the effects, all the dialog should get closed ), When I inject in in the construction like

```
  constructor(
private actions$: Actions,
private dialog: MatDialog,
private categoryService: CategoryService
```

) {}

It shows the error

```
NullInjectorError: No provider for MatDialog!
```

I think this pattern worked before standalone angular, where we could import MatDialogModue to the child feature module and which would provide the dialog. But when switched to standalone, it all got messed up.

Not sure if it is an error or any other way to provide the effects or store other than.

```
  provideState(CATEGORY_FEATURE_KEY, categoryReducer),
  provideEffects(CategoryEffects),
```

in the routes providers array..

Please help, I am stuck at this problem..

Comment: Does importProvidersFrom(MatDialogModule) help?

Comment: It works.. I knew I was missing some detail about switching to standalone..  Thank you so much. You saved my day..

Comment: Glad that did it. Happy coding!